# Displaying table values on dropbox values selection

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascripting . I need to display a table after selecting the dropbox values . Could someone please suggest how this could be done using javascript??

Comment: Show some effort, tell us what you've tried, show us the HTML at least etc.

Comment: Pretty easy.... Hint... use custom attributes and load the data on change of the select box based on the attribute values

Comment: Could you please give us a little more information?  Be specific. If possible post the HTML of the dropbox; where do you want it displayed? ...